# Fetch chrome cast device data after connecting to the android tv

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, android-tv

I am a beginner in Android TV development.
Will be uploading the app in Chrom Cast, so before the actual app starts app should collect the Device serial number.

Thanks in advance.

Gone through the documentation but couldn't get anything.